# Can't display Leaflet HTML through R-Shiny (404 error). How to integrate KML file with rMaps or leaflet-shiny?

Tags: r, networking, leaflet, shiny

I'm having some issues displaying an interactive map in `R-Shiny` that incorporates a KML file. I installed [leaflet-plugins](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins]) and was able to create an HTML file that displays properly by itself in the browser but not within Shiny. This attempt followed an example [here](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/view.php?file=leaflet/kml.html) - the code is available if you view source.

Because this initial version does not require the HTML itself to change, I attempted to follow the samples [here](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/4052973) to include the raw HTML in my page but I receive a 404 error with these as well as when I attempted to include it as an iframe within `R-Shiny` (following [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/wcL9HE15rtk/3ipbwiR75D4J)). I then set up an external facing server for both the KML file and the HTML file and got the same result.

I was able to get a map working without the KML file with [leaflet-shiny](https://github.com/jcheng5/leaflet-shiny) but I'm frankly not sure how to add the KML file and don't see this in the documentation.

Finally, I tried [rMaps](https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps) which does have a "addKML" method, but I can't get it working with various locations of files on my server (

```
map1 = Leaflet$new()
map1$setView(c(45.5236, -122.675), 13)
map1$tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
map1$addKML('http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml')
map1
```

It works without the $addKML line. It might be worth noting that the tilelayer line on example 1 [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps/tree/master/inst/libraries/leaflet/examples) also resulted in a blank map.

I actually have some possibly similar issues hosting derived title layers that are still [unresolved](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94481/generating-interactive-tiles-using-nodejs-mapnik-and-postgis-for-leaflet) which is one reason I opted for uses KML layers for this demo version of the application, which is why I tagged `networking` on here as well. I'm using Digital Ocean.

Thank you for any thoughts or pointers you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be a small issue in the rMaps library. If you inspect the `config.yml` file
https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/leaflet/config.yml you will see that for
content delevery network (cdn) there is reference to
"http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/KML.js". This KML reader is a plugin for leaflet from https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/layer/vector/KML.js. When content is delivered locally:

```
  css: [external/leaflet.css, external/leaflet-rCharts.css, external/legend.css]
  jshead:
    - external/leaflet.js
    - external/leaflet-providers.js
    - external/Control.FullScreen.js
```

there is no reference to this javascript file. We can fix this:

```
require(yaml)
leafletLib <- file.path(find.package("rMaps"), "libraries", "leaflet")
rMapsConfig <- yaml.load_file(file.path(leafletLib, "config.yml"))
# add a kml library
kmlLib <- readLines("http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/KML.js")
write(kmlLib, file.path(leafletLib, "external", "leaflet-kml.js"))
# add the library to config.yml
rMapsConfig$leaflet$jshead <- union(rMapsConfig$leaflet$jshead , "external/leaflet-kml.js")
write(as.yaml(rMapsConfig), file.path(leafletLib, "config.yml"))
```

Now the `config.yml` will contain the necessary link to the KML reader and there is a local copy stored now in `external/leaflet-kml.js`. Our example still wont work however as we will get a `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml.` This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

We will need to have this file served locally. We can place it as a temporary measure in the leaflet folder in the rMaps package. When a map is created this folder gets copied to a temporary file:

```
require(rMaps)
map1 = Leaflet$new()
map1$setView(c(45.5236, -122.675), 13)
map1$tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
map1$addKML('leaflet/placemark.kml')
# temp copy http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml
# to rMaps
sampleKml <- readLines('http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml')
write(sampleKml, file.path(leafletLib, 'placemark.kml'))

# finally try the map
map1

# remove the temp file 
file.remove(file.path(leafletLib, 'placemark.kml'))
```

**UPDATE:**
There is an `addAssets` method in `rCharts` which allows you to add `.js` files. This allows us to simpilfy things and doesnt require us to write a copy of the js file nor edit the `config.yml` file.

```
require(rMaps)
map1 = Leaflet$new()
map1$setView(c(45.5236, -122.675), 13)
map1$tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
map1$addAssets(css = NULL, jshead = 'http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/KML.js')
map1$addKML('leaflet/placemark.kml')
leafletLib <- file.path(find.package("rMaps"), "libraries", "leaflet")
sampleKml <- readLines('http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml')
write(sampleKml, file.path(leafletLib, 'placemark.kml'))
# finally try the map
map1

# remove the temp file 
file.remove(file.path(leafletLib, 'placemark.kml'))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's impressive, I would not have found that out. I'm still facing a purely networking issue: it works on my local machine, but not on my RStudio Server, nor Shiny Server. I'm guessing the location of the KML file needs to change but I'm not sure where.

Comment: @ideamotor to be honest I hadnt tried it on shiny. I will have a look at getting it running on shiny if you like.

Comment: That would be quite awesome, I can set up a minimal example of ui.R and server.R

Comment: Yes please my biggest bugbear with answering shiny questions is having to construct a `runApp(list(ui = ......`. Probably best to make it as a new question.

Comment: Posted it @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637902/networking-for-r-shiny-r-studio-rmaps-with-kml