# Networking for R Shiny / R Studio + rMaps with KML

Tags: r, networking, kml, leaflet, shiny

This is a follow-up for the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618813/cant-display-leaflet-html-through-r-shiny-404-error-how-to-integrate-kml-fil)

Using the code developed by [jdharrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690692/jdharrison) and the discussion [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/108), here is a minimal ui.R:

```
library(shiny);library(rCharts)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
mainPanel(
  tabPanel("Interactive", tags$style('.leaflet {height: 1000px;}'),
  showOutput('mapPlot', 'leaflet'))
  ))              )
```

And a minimal server.R:

```
library(shiny);library(rCharts);library(rMaps)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  output$mapPlot <- renderMap({
    map1 = Leaflet$new()
    map1$setView(c(45.5236, -122.675), 13)
    map1$tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
    map1$addAssets(css = NULL, jshead = 'http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/KML.js')
    map1$addKML('leaflet/placemark.kml')
    leafletLib <- file.path(find.package("rMaps"), "libraries", "leaflet")
    sampleKml <- readLines('http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml')
    write(sampleKml, file.path(leafletLib, 'placemark.kml'))
    map1
  })     })
```

When I run `shiny::runApp()` on my server with `RStudio` or on a live Website I get a blank map, similar to the issue I had locally prior to the aforementioned solution.

I'm sure this has something to do with the location of the KML file and perhaps file permissions, but I'm having some difficulty getting it to work -with- the KML file.

Thank you for any tips or resources you may have.

UPDATE: I tried it locally and get the same result. So, I'm not sure it has something to do with my server networking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here. `rCharts` overrides `rMaps` when they are both loaded up. So the `Leaflet$new` call is actually coming from the `rCharts` package. Also it is not possible to use the `addAssets` method that was utilised previously. It is necessary to change the `libraries/leaflet/config.yml` file and add a
`leaflet-kml.js` link. It is also necessary to download that file to `libraries/leaflet/external/leaflet-kml.js`

First we add the plugin to the rcharts leaflet javascript files

```
require(yaml)
leafletLib <- file.path(find.package("rCharts"), "libraries", "leaflet")
rMapsConfig <- yaml.load_file(file.path(leafletLib, "config.yml"))
# add a kml library
kmlLib <- readLines("http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/KML.js")
write(kmlLib, file.path(leafletLib, "external", "leaflet-kml.js"))
# add the library to config.yml
rMapsConfig$leaflet$jshead <- union(rMapsConfig$leaflet$jshead , "external/leaflet-kml.js")
write(as.yaml(rMapsConfig), file.path(leafletLib, "config.yml"))
```

Now we can look at using shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rMaps)

runApp(
  list(ui =fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)
      ), 
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Interactive", tags$style('.leaflet {height: 1000px;}'),
                   showOutput('mapPlot', 'leaflet'))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    output$mapPlot <- renderUI({
      map1 = Leaflet$new()
      map1$setView(c(45.5236, -122.675), 13)
      map1$tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
      map1$addKML('leaflet/placemark.kml')
      leafletLib <- file.path(find.package("rCharts"), "libraries", "leaflet")
      sampleKml <- readLines('http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml')
      write(sampleKml, file.path(leafletLib, 'placemark.kml'))
      HTML(map1$html(chartId = "mapPlot"))})     
  })
)
```

[image: new image]

Comment: Sweet! I was about to have to abandon all this and go with geoJSON using togeojson, but I already have my colors and labels working in KML, thanks a ton.

Comment: Happy to help. Its a temporary fix. Ramnath is working on the next iteration of rCharts/rMaps so the above will not be necessary.

Comment: So it appears that this function over-rides the colors in the KML file with blueish colors. http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Polygon/treasureIsland.kml should be green not blue. Should I open another question for this? Unfortunately I don't know where to start to pin-point this. I think it must have something to do with the CSS for Leaflet.

Comment: This is an issue with the plugin https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/56. It was supposed to be fixed but this https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/56#issuecomment-24949894 still shows blue when using all libraries directly independent of shiny/rMaps/rCharts etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For that reason I'm going with geoJSON for now. Ramnathv has a couple good examples for geoJSON @ http://ramnathv.github.io/bikeshare/slides/#1 and https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps/blob/master/inst/libraries/leaflet/examples/example10.R for those following along. Another note: I think you have to use renderMap in order to get the map to be reactive, or least in my code that was the case. FWIW, it's not clear to me how to change the size of the map with renderMap without hard-coding options(R_CHART_HEIGHT = X) etc.